# Show age of user

Tags: ruby

I need to ask the user for their birth year, and then display every year from the birth year to 2017 with the age for each year.

I started with this:

```
puts "when are you born (year) ?"
birth_year = gets.to_i
birth_year.upto(2017){ |birth_year| puts birth_year }
```

I miss the part to display the age. I tried some stuff like:

```
puts birth_year.upto(2017) - birth_year
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Your block variable name is semantically incorrect. Rename it and then you'll easily see the correct calculation.

Comment: "Did not work" is not a useful diagnostic. Error messages, especially the *exact text* of those, is a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a different form of block like this:

```
puts "when are you born (year) ?"
birth_year = gets.to_i    
birth_year.upto(2017) do |iterating_year|
  puts "Year: #{iterating_year}"
  puts "Age: #{iterating_year - birth_year }"
end
```

Or if you want it all in the same line try this - but it's less readable:

```
birth_year.upto(2017) { |iterating_year|  puts "Year: #{iterating_year}"; puts "Age: #{iterating_year - birth_year }" }
```

#### Naming block variables

- Recommendation: Do not use the same variable name in your block as you have outside the block - that's just confusing. In this particular case, with the code as you have written it, the `birth_year` you have defined outside the block will have fallen out of scope, and the block parameter will take on the iterating years value: 2001, 2002, 2003 etc.

[image: Same and confusing - avoid]

#### String Interpolation

This is when join strings together. One method you could use is to write some ruby code inside a string - you need a hash tag and opening and closing curly brackets to make it work. See [this link for more](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html) info or google "ruby string interpoloation".

Comment: Since the OP appears to be new to Ruby, you may wish to mention string interpolation.

Comment: Ruby will actually warn about "variable shadowing" which is using the same name twice in different, overlapping scopes, if the `-w` flag is enabled. It's a good idea to avoid it not only because it's confusing, but because it can lead to unexpected results.